# How can one start an \item with a math align environment?

Tags: latex

In latex, I need to start an item in an enumerate list with an align* environment, but this environment starts with a new line, leaving an ugly empty space.

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. e^{ix}=cos x+i sin x

   e^{i\pi} = -1

   e^{i\pi}+1=0

What I'm trying:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{align*}
      e^{ix}&=\cos x+i\sin x\\
      e^{i\pi}&=-1\\
      e^{i\pi}+1&=0
      \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there some other environment for this?

(I know that it is not recommended to start an item with a displayed math formula, but in this case I need to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \hfill$\begin{aligned}[t]
      e^{ix}&=\cos x+i\sin x\\
      e^{i\pi}&=-1\\
      e^{i\pi}+1&=0
      \end{aligned}$\hfill\mbox{}
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A hack similar to the one in the accepted answer: the environment `matrix` needs no package to work and has no visible delimiters:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\begin{matrix}
  e^{ix}&=\cos x+i\sin x\\
  e^{i\pi}&=-1\\
  e^{i\pi}+1&=0
\end{matrix}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The output seems to me similar to the one you wanted to achieve:

[image: screenshot of output]